# Как правильно сформировать POST запрос?

Tags: laravel, http, request, rest

routes/api.php
[image: routes/api.php]

Controllers/UserController.php
[image: UserController]

User Model

[image: usermodel]

Migration

[image: migration]

Тест в POSTMAN
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот сообщение об ошибке:

```
 Response:{
       {
          "message":"The given data was invalid.",
          "errors":{
             "name":[
                "The name field is required."
             ],
             "surname":[
                "The surname field is required."
             ],
             "patronymic":[
                "The patronymic field is required."
             ],
             "sex":[
                "The sex field is required."
             ],
             "birthday":[
                "The birthday field is required."
             ],
             "country":[
                "The country field is required."
             ],
             "city":[
                "The city field is required."
             ],
             "telephone":[
                "The telephone field is required."
             ],
             "email":[
                "The email field is required."
             ],
             "password":[
                "The password field is required."
             ]
          }
       }
    }
 class UserController extends Controller
 {
 public function signup (Request $request) {      

     $this->validate($request->all(), [
         'name' => 'required',
         'surname' => 'required',
         'patronymic'  => 'required',
         'sex' => 'required',
         'birthday' => 'required|date',
         'country' => 'required',
         'city' => 'required',
         'telephone' => 'required',
         'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
         'password' => 'required|max:32'
     ]);

     $user = new User([
         'name' => $request->input('name'),
         'surname' => $request->input('surname'),
         'patronymic' => $request->input('patronymic'),
         'sex' => $request->input('sex'),
         'birthday' => $request->input('birthday'),
         'country' => $request->input('country'),
         'city' => $request->input('city'),
         'telephone' => $request->input('telephone'),
         'email' => $request->input('email'),
         'password' => bcrypt($request->input('password'))
     ]);

     $user->save();

     return response()->json([
         'message' => 'Successfully, new User created!!!'
     ], 201);
 }
```

}

```
   class User extends Authenticatable
{
 use Notifiable;

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'surname', 'patronymic', 'sex', 'birthday', 'country', 'city', 'telephone', 'email', 'password'
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];
```

}

Comment: Переведите вопрос на русский, пожалуйста.

Comment: .. и в виде текста.

Comment: + вся текстовая информация (код, json), должна быть в вопросе в виде текста, а не скриншотов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во первых, в теле запроса отправляется `json` объект, поэтому валидатор жалуется на отсутсвие полей.

Во вторых, `json` из тела запроса можно забрать с помощью `Input::all();`

И в третьих, валидацию нужно переделать, так как выше написал, у тебя не POST параметры идут, а в теле запроса `json` объект.

**upd**
Совсем ступил, если хочешь чтобы все так же осталось в коде, то нужно сменить просто сам запрос:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выбираешь вкладку `Body` там `form-data` и заполняешь как на картинке поля

Comment: Большое спасибо, все по полочкам объяснил!